# make changes to the position of navigation bar depend on scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

my question is how can i make changes to the position of navigation bar depend on scroll bar or exposed area of header ?

here is the initial position of my navigation bar:-
[image]

---

**what i want is that the position of the navigation is not fixed but absolute `position: absolute;` until i scroll down my browser till the navigation bar reaches the top of the page** (as you can see in the gif) **then i want its position changes to fixed**.

```
#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 290px;
    z-index:999;
    right:0px;
}
```

[image]

as when navigation bar reaches the top then i want its position changes to fixed `position: fixed;`

[image]

```
#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 12px;
    z-index:999;
    right:6px;
}
```

as you can see in this gif its position changes to fix

[image]

[image]

**my second question is does it possible only using CSS or do i also have to use java script as well ?**

here is my code:-

```css
header {
    width:100%; 
    height:350px; 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-1;
    border:3px solid grey;
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
} 

#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 12px;
    z-index:999;
    right:6px;
}

#navul01 li {
    float: left;
}

#navul01 li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:2px solid white;
}

#navul01 li a:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}


#subjects_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}

#subjects_nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:3px solid white;
    transition: 1s;
}

#subjects_nav li a:hover {
    margin: 0 -5%;
}

#physics_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#chemistry_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#maths_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#space {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   </head>

   <body> 
      <div class="main-wrapper"> 
         <header> </header> 
         <div><nav>
            <ul id="navul01">
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#news">blog</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about">contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav></div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul id="space">
            <li><a></a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul id="subjects_nav">
            <li><a id="physics_image" href="#home">PHYSICS</a></li>
            <li><a id="chemistry_image" href="pages\chemistry\chemistry.html">CHEMISTRY</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you make any attempt? did you do any research at all? do you know about [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)?

Comment: @Occam's_Razor yes i did a research but couldn't find anything

Comment: @Occam's_Razor look at my second question i want to know does it possible only using CSS

Comment: ok, good luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a little JS to catch the user scrolling.

Now, prior to that, you need to get the "nav" position when it is to `position: absolute`. Use a CSS class to add it on load.

If the user scroll more than the "absolute" position, remove the "absolute" class. If the user scrolls back to less... Re-add the class.

;)

```js
var nav = $("#navul01");
nav.addClass("absolute");
var navPos = nav.offset().top;

$(window).on("scroll", function(){

  if( this.scrollY > navPos ){
    nav.removeClass("absolute");
  }else{
    nav.addClass("absolute");
  }
});
```

```css
header {
    width:100%; 
    height:350px; 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-1;
    border:3px solid grey;
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
} 

#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 12px;
    z-index:999;
    right:6px;
}

#navul01.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top:290px;
}

#navul01 li {
    float: left;
}

#navul01 li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:2px solid white;
}

#navul01 li a:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}


#subjects_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}

#subjects_nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:3px solid white;
    transition: 1s;
}

#subjects_nav li a:hover {
    margin: 0 -5%;
}

#physics_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#chemistry_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#maths_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#space {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body> 
      <div class="main-wrapper"> 
         <header> </header> 
         <div><nav>
            <ul id="navul01">
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#news">blog</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about">contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav></div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul id="space">
            <li><a></a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul id="subjects_nav">
            <li><a id="physics_image" href="#home">PHYSICS</a></li>
            <li><a id="chemistry_image" href="pages\chemistry\chemistry.html">CHEMISTRY</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Louys_Patrice_Bessette thanks this is exactly what i wanted

Comment: You also can "adjust" the comparison to take the fixed top position in account... like: `this.scrollY - 12 > navPos`... So that would be even smoother. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the scroll position of the document with the offset position of the navigation. And if the scroll position is bigger, then add a class to it.

I made you an example of the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // first get the starting position of the navigation
  $scrollPosition = $('#navigation').offset().top;
});


$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    // fire compare function on document scroll
    compareScrollPositionToNavigation($scrollPosition);
});


function compareScrollPositionToNavigation(){
    // check if document scroll position is bigger than position of navigation
    // if yes add class fixed to navigation / if not remove it
    if($(document).scrollTop() > $scrollPosition){
      $('#navigation').addClass('fixed');
     } else {
      $('#navigation').removeClass('fixed');
     }
}
```

Here is the full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tqcsgmru/9/